# Deriving a recurrence relationship for derivatives of $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation, recurrence-relations

I was trying to derive a recurrence relantionship for computing the $k$-th derivative of the function (hoping no error during copy)

$$
f(x) = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}
$$

Using maple I've seen the following derivatives
$$
\begin{array}{l}
f^{(0)}(x) = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \\
f^{(1)}(x) = \frac{1}{(x^2 + 1)x} - \frac{f(x)}{x} \\
f^{(2)}(x) = \frac{-2}{(x^2+1)^2} + \frac{-2}{(x^2 + 1)x^2} + \frac{2f(x)}{x^2} \\
f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{8}{(x^2+1)^3x^{-1}} + \frac{4}{(x^2+1)^2x} + \frac{6}{(x^2+1)x^3} - \frac{6f(x)}{x^3} \\
f^{(4)}(x) = \frac{-48}{(x^2+1)^4x^{-2}} + \frac{-8}{(x^2+1)^3} + \frac{-16}{(x^2+1)^2 x^2} + \frac{-24}{(x^2+1)x^4} + \frac{24 f(x)}{x^4} \\
f^{(5)}(x) = \frac{384}{(x^2+1)^5 x^{-3}} + \frac{-48}{(x^2+1)^4x^{-1}} + \frac{64}{(x^2+1)^3x} + \frac{80}{(x^2+1)^2x^3} + \frac{120}{(x^2+1)x^5} - \frac{120f(x)}{x^5}
\end{array}
$$

This lead me to the following expression, as summation, for the $k$-th derivative

$$
f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{c_{j,k}}{(x^2+1)^jx^{k-2j+2}} + (-1)^k \frac{k! f(x)}{x^k}
$$

Firstly do you agree with me that the coefficients $c_{j,k}$ fully describes the $k$-th derivative of $f$? If not can you point out the mistake I made?

The next step I would writing $f^{(k+1)}$ in terms of the coefficients $c_{j,k}$ from there I should be able to derive a recurrence relationship for the coefficients (like a triangular table that would allow me to derive the coefficients $c_{j,k}$ for given $k$ and $j = 1 \ldots k$).

Do you think there's a smarter way to do achieve the same result? maybe easier? the computations involved here are quite messy.

Update : here is my attempt

$$
f^{(k+1)}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^k c_{j,k}\left[ \frac{-2jx}{(x^2+1)^{j+1}x^{k-2j+2}} +  \frac{k-2j+2}{(x^2+1)^jx^{k-2j+3}}\right] + \frac{(-1)^k {k!}}{(x^2+1)x^{k+1}} + (-1)^{k+1} {(k+1)!} \frac{f(x)}{x^{k+1}}
$$

I got stuck now...

Comment: The problem is that you do not have a recurrence relation allow us to deduce the coefficients $c_{j,k}$

Comment: That is indeed my question... Am I going through the right path? I want to derive such relationship.

Comment: *If* your formula is *correct* then $f^{(k+1)}=(f^{(k)})'$ leads to a senseful recurrence. Have you tried ?

Comment: Still working on that, but I suppose it will lead me to something at some point. I'll post later my calculations. I've been trying to see if I can use maple to do the computations for me because are quite tedious to do by hand.

Comment: Compute the formal derivative of $f^{(k)}(x)$ in terms of $c_{k,j}$ and equate it to the formal expression for $f^{(k+1)}(x)$ that depends on $c_{k+1,j}$. That gives a recurrence relation for the wanted coefficients.

Comment: If I derive the expression can you help to correct it if it is wrong?

Comment: Additionally, the wanted coefficient can be directly computed from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: I don't really know how to use the theorem... If you could give a scratch that would be very useful. I can try to complete the necessary details.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Lagrange–Bürmann formula" for how to derive the coefficients?

Comment: I've tried to understand how to apply the theorem but I don't really understand how were you suggesting to apply it. I've seen some examples of application (like finding roots of trascendental equations). I've also tried to find some reference, but I can't find anything about  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n\in\mathbb{N}$

It's $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n }\arctan x=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(xf(x))=n\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1} }f(x)+ x\frac{d^n}{dx^n }f(x)$$ and for $x>0$ (and proofed by induction) one gets $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n }\arctan x=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\frac{\sin(n \arctan\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{1+x^2}^n}$$

It follows that the recursion for the derivatives of $\displaystyle f(x):=\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ is
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n }f(x)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\frac{\sin(n \arctan\frac{1}{x})}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}^n}-\frac{n}{x} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}f(x)$$

*Note*:

Instead of $\arctan\frac{1}{x}$ I should write $\,$*arccot(x)*$\,$ (so that we can also use $x<0$) but it's not declared here.

*Hint*:

A proof can be found e.g. in http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2010/090408-2.pdf with $\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \arctan(x) = x \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) + n \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} f(x)$?. Also how did u get $\sin(n \arctan \frac{1}{x})$? If I compute some derivative of $\arctan$ using maple there's no square root involved. Please can you expound the derivation?.

Comment: @user8469759 : Thank you very much, it was a typo. I will not do the whole derivation of $\arctan$ here but it is based substantially on $\sin((n+1)z)=\cos(z)\sin(nz)+\sin(z)\cos(nz)$ with $z:=\arctan\frac{1}{x}$, $x>0$, $\sin z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $\cos z=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Comment: Can you point out where can I find the proof? I assume there's somewhere. Google provide me stuff with like "http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/20/02/"

Comment: I don't know where a proof is. I have looked for it now like you and found with "nth derivative of arctan x" e.g. the link http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2010/090408-2.pdf . There is a proof.

Comment: I'm having a look.

Comment: Sounds ok, it meake sense now. The only thing is that you wrote $\arctan \frac{1}{x}$ while tha paper use $\arcsin \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}  \right)$ are they equivalent and I'm not realizing that?

Comment: I wanted to write arccot(x) (as I have written above) but LaTeX doesn't support it here. I have checked it, yes it's the same because of $\sin z=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot(z)^2}}$, the $\pm$ depends on the value range. :-)

Comment: @user8469759 : Is this recursion o.k. for you or do you like to have another kind of solution ?

Comment: Compared to my original question and purpose the expression you provided me is exactly what I was looking for. It's not exactly what I was asking in my question, but it's o.k. Do you think it could be possible use the same stile to find a general expression for the derivative of $\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}$?

Comment: I don't know the $n^{th}$ derivation of the $\arcsin$-function, but if you find one (or calculate one - perhaps if you manipulate the proof for $\arctan$) then of course you can use the same method for $\frac{\arcsin x}{x}$ as we have it here for $\frac{\arctan x}{x}$.

Comment: I imagine that is the main problem. I wonder in your answer how people had guessed the solution... the formula is quite nasty. xD

Comment: @user8469759 : The main thing is that it works. And to guess - no, usually we find a solution by using some learned methods, seeing some regularities und combined this with try and error. :-)

Comment: @user8469759 (only a hint): For $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\arcsin x$ one can define $\cosh z:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ (because of the same value range) and then one has $\frac{dz}{dx}=\cosh^2 z$. We start with $\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x=\cosh z$ and continue $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\arcsin x=\sinh z\cosh^2 z$ and so on ... . It's a very useful method for the multiple derivation of  $\arcsin x$ but it doesn't become simple as it is with $\arctan x$.